# Is there a Foobar2000 component that would display only the playing playlist in the Default UI?

Tags: audio, music, foobar2000, components, addons

I use 'Tabs' component to display the components that I want in the Default UI.

Under one of the Tabs I have 'Playlist view' and under another I have 'Playlist tabs'

I use the later to keep playlists that I use often, for example two separate pls with separate types of  internet radios. Other music that I play is always put in other tabs.

[image]

I started using 'Playlist view' and 'Playlist Tabs' in parallel because **I though that 'Playlist view' will display the playing playlist - but in fact it displays the selected one.** As in my case the selection is done and displayed in the Playlist Tabs, 'Playlist view' brings no plus for me, because I will always see the same thing under both (the selected playlist), and will see the playing one not because it is the one playing, but because it is selected.

What I want to know is:

- is there a Foobar component that would display the playing playlist (the one with the playing track) ***and only that*** - so that I can put that under the tab that now is taken by Playlist View?

(I am not asking how to see the playing track and playlist. Answer: by double-clicking the status bar.)

Comment: I'm looking for the exact same thing. Have you been able to find anything? Foobar's playlist is so confusing. I think programs like MusicBee or Winamp got it better

Comment: @AlirezaNoori - foobar has multiple components (modules) and some of them are about the interface.  What you see there by default and don't like is the 'Playlist Tabs' container. What you want is a different component called 'Playlist view'. It is the one that I am describing in my question above when I complain that it switches to the selected playlist instead of the now-playing one. In your case it should be ok as you will never select another playlist but the default one. I am using all in parallel you just have to replays Playlist tabs with Playlist view. See below how.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori -  to replace Playlist tabs with Playlist view: first make a backup of you present layout (Preferences>Display>Default user interface>Export theme. The same path to import theme). Then go to View>Layout>Enable layout editing mode. Right click on a playlist tab and select 'Replace UI element'. Then scroll down and select 'Plylist view' (Under playlist renderers). Un-ckeck 'editing mode'. You can now export your new theme. - Or you might just install/import that theme that I created and uploaded [here](https://mega.co.nz/#!4BBDCSRS!mbr2NcqLLRyTbrXDbda6cej8N1FBMwgKmLiIijedcYQ).

Comment: @AlirezaNoori - now i don't really understand what you are saying: "remove all the playlists and combine them into a single one. That way the playlist tabs would only show 1 tab." One single tab is nonsense, the very idea of using tabs is the ability to switch between them. So, maybe I understand that you don't want tabs at all, just one single playlist and no tabs. I have already presented the solution for that, just install the theme uploaded at the link posted in my comment above. I will remove some of my comments hoping that you had read them. You should do the same.

Comment: Here's the link to my question. I'll remove my comments. Thanks\